# Finding the particular solution of a differential equation using at least three different methods.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the particular solution $(x^2+6y^2)dx-4xydy=0$; when $x=1$, $y=1$ using at least three different methods.

I have done the first two. Can somebody help me with the third method.

Method 1: Homogenous Equation

Let $y=vx; dy=vdx+xdv$

$(x^2+6x^2v^2)dx-4x(vx)(vdx+xdv)=0$

$(x^2+2x^2v^2)dx-4x^3vdv=0$

$(1+2v^2)dx-4xvdv=0$

$\int\frac{dx}{4x}-\int\frac{v}{1+2v^2}dv=0$

$\ln{x}-\ln{(2v^2+1)}=C$

$\ln{(\frac{x}{2v^2+1})}=\ln{C}$

$\frac{x}{2v^2+1}=\frac{1}{C}$

$C=3$

$3x=2v^2+1$

$3x^3=2y^2+x^2$

$2y^2=x^2(3x-1)$

The particular solution by method 1 is $2y^2=x^2(3x-1)$.

Method 2: Bernoulli Equation

$2y\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{x^2+6y^2}{2x}=0$

$2y\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{3y^2}{x}=\frac{x}{2}$

Let $v=y^2; dv=2ydy$

$\frac{dv}{dx}-\frac{3v}{x}=\frac{x}{2}$

$P(x)=-3x^{-1}$; I.F.$=e^{-3\int x^{-1}dx}=x^{-3}$

$vx^-3=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dx}{x^2}$

$2vx^{-3}=-x^{-1}+C^{-1}$

$2y^2x^{-3}+x^{-1}=C^{-1}$

$C=\frac{1}{3}$

$2y^2+x^2=3x^3$

$2y^2=x^2(3x-1)$

The particular solution by method 2 is also $2y^2=x^2(3x-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check if the ODE is exact:
$$\Delta=\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+6y^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-4xy)=16y\ne0.$$
So it's not exact, but as
$$\frac{\Delta}{N}=\frac{16y}{-4xy}=-\frac{4}{x}=f(x),$$
we can get an integrating factor with the form
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)=\exp\left(\int-\frac{4}{x}\mathrm{d} x\right)=e^{-4\log x}=x^{-4}.$$
Now, let's apply our IF, multiplying both sides by it:
$$x^{-4}(x^2+6y^2)\mathrm{d}x-4x^{-3}y\,\mathrm{d}y=0,$$
Let's check if the new ODE is exact (it must be, but just in case),
$$\Delta'=\frac{\partial M'}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N'}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigl[x^{-4}(x^2+6y^2)\bigr]-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-4x^{-3}y)=0.$$

So, we are looking for a function $F(x,y)$ that satisfy
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} & =x^{-4}(x^2+6y^2);\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} & =-4x^{-3}y.
\end{align}
From the second condition,
$$F(x,y)=\int-4x^{-3}y\,\mathrm{d}y+\varphi(x)=-2x^{-3}y^2+\varphi(x).$$
Now, we can plug $F$ in the first condition:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl[-2x^{-3}y^2+\varphi(x)\bigr]=x^{-4}(x^2+6y^2) & \Longrightarrow6x^{-4}y^2+\varphi'(x)=x^{-4}(x^2+6y^2)\Longrightarrow\\
& \Longrightarrow\varphi'(x)=x^{-2}\Longrightarrow\varphi(x)=-\frac{1}{x}.
\end{align*}

So, the solution takes the form $F(x,y)=C$, and is
$$-2x^{-3}y^2-\frac{1}{x}=C\Longrightarrow2y^2=-Cx^3-x^2.$$

If $y=1$ when $x=1$,
$$2=-C-1\Longrightarrow C=-3,$$
and we we have
$$2y^2=3x^3-x^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Compare
$$(x^2+6y^2)dx-4xydy=0~~~~(1)$$
with $$Mdx+Ndy=0 \implies \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=12y,~~ \frac{\partial  N}{dx}=-4y $$ It's integrating factor is
$$I=\exp \left(\int \frac{12y +4y}{-4xy}\right)=x^{-4}$$
Multiplying (1) with $x^{-4}$,(1) becomes an exact ODE:
$$(x^{-2}+6x^{-4} y^2) dx- 4x^{-3} ydy==0$$
It's solution is
$$\int (x^{-2}+6x^{-4}y^2) dx~~~ \text{(treat y as constant)}=C$$
$$-x^{-1}-2x^{-3}y^{2}=C$$
By the condition $y(1)=1$, we get $C=-3$
Finally $$2y^2=3x^3-x^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2+6y^2)dx-4xydy=0$$
$$(x^2+6y^2)dx-2xdy^2=0$$
$$x^2dx+2(3y^2dx-xdy^2)=0$$
Multiply by $x^2$:
$$x^4dx+2(3x^2y^2dx-x^3dy^2)=0$$
$$x^4dx+2(y^2dx^3-x^3dy^2)=0$$
Divide by $x^6$:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x^2}-2d\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)=0$$
Integrate.
$$\dfrac {1}{x}+2\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)=C$$
$$y(1)=1 \implies C=3$$
Therefore:
$$x^2+2y^2=3x^3$$